# Datetime manipulation in R

Tags: r, datetime, xlsx

I have a data set in an xlsx file. As seen in the attached picture it contains news updates over a time period. For every date there can be more updates, but the date is only listed at the top and does not appear in each row as a datetime. Any suggestions on how to attach the date to the below rows would be much appreciated. That is, I wish to have a datetime stamp on each row. I work in R Studio

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your non-date data always includes **":"** inside it.

```
    logic <- data.frame(L=rle(!grepl(":",data))$length,
            TF=rle(!grepl(":",data))$value)

    out <- data.frame(Date=rep(data[!grepl(":",data)],logic[logic$TF=="FALSE",1]),
            Other=data[grepl(":",data)])

    out$Date <- as.Date(as.character(out$Date),"%d/%B/%Y")

    out
```

gives,

```
        Date                        Other
1 2020-05-27 02:02:23 PM - Bla1 Bla1 Bla1
2 2020-05-27 08:20:27 AM - Bla2 Bla2 Bla2
3 2020-05-21 08:04:20 PM - Bla3 Bla3 Bla3
```

**Data:**

```
data <- c("27/May/2020", 
    "02:02:23 PM - Bla1 Bla1 Bla1",
    "08:20:27 AM - Bla2 Bla2 Bla2",
    "21/May/2020",
    "08:04:20 PM - Bla3 Bla3 Bla3")
```